# How to prevent capistrano replacing newlines?

Tags: ruby, capistrano, heredoc, capistrano3

I want to run some shell scripts remotely as part of my capistrano setup. To test that functionality, I use this code:

```
execute <<SHELL
cat <<TEST
something
TEST
SHELL
```

However, that is actually running `/usr/bin/env cat <<TEST; something; TEST` which is obviously not going to work. How do I tell capistrano to execute the heredoc as I have written it, without converting the newlines into semicolons?

I have Capistrano Version: 3.2.1 (Rake Version: 10.3.2) and do not know ruby particularly well, so there might be something obvious I missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* it might work to just specify the arguments to `cat` as a second, er, argument to `execute`:

```
cat_args = <<SHELL
<<TEST
something
TEST
SHELL

execute "cat", cat_args
```

From the code @DavidGrayson posted, it looks like only the command (the first argument to `execute`) is sanitized.

I agree with David, though, that the simpler way might be to put the data in a file, which is [what the SSHKit documentation suggests](https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md#upload-a-file-from-a-stream):

> ### Upload a file from a stream
>
> ```
> on hosts do |host|
>   file = File.open('/config/database.yml')
>   io   = StringIO.new(....)
>   upload! file, '/opt/my_project/shared/database.yml'
>   upload! io,   '/opt/my_project/shared/io.io.io'
> end
> ```
>
> The IO streaming is useful for uploading something rather than "cat"ing it, for example
>
> ```
> on hosts do |host|
>   contents = StringIO.new('ALL ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL')
>   upload! contents, '/etc/sudoers.d/yolo'
> end
> ```
>
> This spares one from having to figure out the correct escaping sequences for something like "`echo(:cat, '...?...', '> /etc/sudoers.d/yolo')`".

This seems like it would work perfectly for your use case.

Comment: That works, but only for very simple cases. It lets me compress the string to echo, but I don't think it will support real multiline commands. +1 anyway.

Comment: @Benubird See my updated answer for another option. Hope it's helpful!

Comment: Aha! Yes, that's perfect. I considered uploading a file, but didn't want to because it makes it hard to use variables in it, but I hadn't realized you could upload a string to a file.

Answer (score 0):

The code responsible for this sanitization can be found in `SSHKit::Command#sanitize_command!`, which is called by that class's `initialize` method.  You can see the source code here:

https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit/blob/9ac8298c6a62582455b1b55b5e742fd9e948cefe/lib/sshkit/command.rb#L216-226

You might consider monkeypatching it to do nothing by adding something like this to the top of your Rakefile:

```
SSHKit::Command  # force the class to load so we can re-open it
class SSHKit::Command
  def sanitize_command!
    return if some_condition
    super
  end
end
```

This is risky and could introduce problems in other places; for example there might be parts of Capistrano that assume that the command has no newlines.

You are probably better off making a shell script that contains the heredoc or putting the heredoc in a file somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is the solution I figured out myself, in case it's useful for someone else:

```
str = %x(
base64 <<TEST
some
thing
TEST
).delete("\n")
execute "echo #{str} | base64 -d | cat -"
```

As you can see, I'm base64 encoding my command, sending it through, then decoding it on the server side where it can be evaluated intact. This works, but it's a real ugly hack - I hope someone can come up with a better solution.